# How would I hash a rectangle?

Tags: java, hash

I have a Rectangle class. It has a length, breadth and area (all ints). I want to hash it such that every rectangle with the same length and breadth hashes to the same value. What is a way to do this?

EDIT: I understand its a broad question. Thats why I asked for "a" way to do it. Not the best way.

Comment: How about something like `31*b + l`?

Comment: Why is this guaranteed to serve the purpose? In other words, whats the guarantee using this formuala, two different rectangles will never hash to the same value?

Comment: Also, I understand its a broad question. Thats why I asked for "a" way to do it. Not the best way.

Comment: Re: "Why is this guaranteed to serve the purpose? In other words, whats the guarantee using this formuala, two different rectangles will never hash to the same value?": Your question did not ask for such a guarantee; if that's what you want, please correct your question. (Also, I think such a guarantee is impossible in the general case, though it may be possible if you have unmentioned restrictions on the set of legal rectangles.)

Comment: Do you have any restriction on the length and breadth ? If not, you will run into integer overflow issues if you try to store the area of rectangles with length * breadth > Integer.MAX_INT.

Comment: @ruakh: Fair enough. Also, I have restrictions and overflow won't happen.

Comment: Voting to close. From your various comments, it's clear that you have additional requirements and guarantees that you're not telling us about; that makes it pointless to try to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

A good and simple scheme is to calculate the hash for a pair of integers as follows:

```
hash = length * CONSTANT + width
```

Empirically, you will get best results (i.e. the fewest number collisions) if `CONSTANT` is a prime number.  A lot of people<sup>1</sup> recommend a value like `31`, but the best choice depends on the most likely *range* of the `length` and `width` value.  If they are strictly bounded, and small enough, then you could do better than `31`.

However, `31` is probably good enough for practical purposes<sup>2</sup>.  A few collisions at this level is unlikely to make a significant performance difference, and even a perfect hashing function does not eliminate collisions at the hash table level ... where you use the modulus of the hash value.

---

<sup>1 - I'm not sure where this number comes from, or whether there are empirical studies to back it up ... in the general case.  I *suspect* it comes from hashing of (ASCII) strings.  But `31` is prime ... and it is a Mersenne prime (`2^7 - 1`) which means it could be computed using a shift and a subtraction if hardware multiple is slow.</sup>

<sup>2 - I'm excluding cases where you need to worry about someone deliberately creating hash function collisions in an attempt to "break" something.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Apache Commons library, which has a `HashCodeBuilder` class. Assuming you have a `Rectangle` class with a `width` and a `height`, you can add the following method:

```
@Override
public int hashCode(){
  return new HashCodeBuilder().append(width).append(height).append(children).toHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want (as clarified in your comment on the question) is not possible. There are N possible hashCodes, one for each int, where N is approximately 4.2 billion. Assuming rectangles must have positive dimensions, there are ((N * N) / 4) possible rectangles. How do you propose to make them fit into N hashCodes? When N is > 4, you have more possible rectangles than hashCodes.

Comment: I don't think it's correct to say that "There are ((N * N) / 4) possible rectangles". That would be true (plus or minus a fencepost error) if the class had only `length` and `breadth`, but it also has an `area` of type `int`, such that N/2 is an upper bound on `length * breadth`, thereby sharply limiting the number of possible rectangles. (But your main point, that there are more possible rectangles than legal `int`s, is still correct.)

Comment: Yah, I forgot to account for area. :-(

Comment: Good point, but for my problem, 4.2 billion (= N) are enough. I don't need N*N/4 rectangles for my specific problem.

Comment: @Cricketer Have a static int that starts at -MAXINT, and a local variable hashcode in rectangle. When you construct each rectangle, assign the hashcode the value of the counter and incrememnt the counter by one. Every rectangle will have a unique hashcode until you hit MAXINT.