# HashSet contains() returns false for custom object. hashCode() and equals() seem to be implemented correctly

Tags: java

I have the following simple Rectangle class. If two rectangles have the same height and width, they are equal and have the same hashcode. I added a new rectangle to a hashSet.

```
Set<Rectangle> set = new HashSet<Rectangle>();
set.add(new Rectangle(3,3));
```

When I try to call contains on a new rectangle with same height and width, it returns false.

`set.contains(new Rectangle(3,3))` returns false. I can't figure out why. Any ideas?

```
   public class Rectangle implements Comparable<Rectangle> {
            final int height, width, area, minimumEdge, maximumEdge;

            public Rectangle(int height, int width) {
                this.height = height;
                this.width = width;
                area = height * width;
                maximumEdge = height > width ? height : width;
                minimumEdge = height < width ? height : width;
            }

            public int compareTo(Rectangle rect2) {
                if (rect2.minimumEdge > this.minimumEdge) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (rect2.minimumEdge < this.minimumEdge) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            public int hashCode(){
                return ((width + height)*31);
            }

            public boolean equals(Rectangle rect2){
                return (this.height == rect2.height && this.width == rect2.width);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You seem to have misread the answers to previous questions on how to create a hashcode for a rectangle; e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18543114/how-would-i-hash-a-rectangle. Your hashcode method is going to give you a lot of collisions.

Comment: Side note: `maximumEdge = height > width ? height : width` = `maximumEdge = Math.max(height, width)` and `minimumEdge = height < width ? height : width` = `Math.min(height, width)`

Answer (score 14):

You haven't actually overridden `equals()`.

You created a new `equals(Rectangle)` method, which has nothing to do with the virtual `equals(Object)` method.

This is why you should always add `@Override` when trying to override methods.

Comment: Or create/use a template in your IDE.  One that overrides the correct equals, and implements hashCode.

Comment: @user949300 - Yes, but it is a good idea to know how to write correct programs *without* using the IDE's training wheels.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
public boolean equals(Rectangle rect2){
            return (this.height == rect2.height && this.width == rect2.width);
        }
```

You make your own equals method, not override superclass method.

You must write like:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Rectangle rect2 = (Rectangle) obj;
    return (this.height == rect2.height && this.width == rect2.width);
}
```